Animation changes when creating control rig (Mixamo)
thanks for reading. I downloaded some animations from Mixamo and they seem to work great, but I need to modify them a little bit. When I try to use the Mixamo plugin to create a Control Rig, the animation revolves around the hipbone, instead of the other constraints. Does anyone know how I can fix this? (or an alternate way to modify the animation using inverse kinematics on the hands?). I'm using 4.2.3 and the Mixamo plugin for Blender 4+. Thanks!
Animation working when first imported to Blender:

Option selected for Create Control Rig:

Setting for Create Control Rig:

Animation not working (revolves around the hip bone) after creating control rig:

